VB.NET Error after calling Dim secret = Await client.GetSecretAsync
I have an error immediately after calling the third line in the below:
Dim kvUri = $"https://{KEY_VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net"

Dim client = New SecretClient(New Uri(kvUri), New DefaultAzureCredential())

Dim secret = Await client.GetSecretAsync(KEY_ID)

KEY_VAULT_NAME and KEY_ID are String and have proper values.
The code is inside Main of a module which is marked as
 Public Async Sub Main()

The error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
After a while the secret.Value.Value gets the desired sting but I have trouble understanding why I have the error and how to fix this issue.
I tried Microsoft Documentation and StackOverflow

Your code is probably trying to use secret when it is still Nothing. You should change any Async Sub methods to Async Function ... Of Task and Await them.

Where is the error occurring?  On one of the lines here, or in something you didn't show?


VB.NET error occurs after calling Dim secret = Await client.GetSecretAsync().

Use the code below to get the secret value of Azure Key Vault using Visual Basic .NET:
Code:
Imports Azure.Identity
Imports Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets

Module Program
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim secretValue = GetSecretAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        Console.WriteLine($"Secret value: {secretValue}")
    End Sub

    Private Async Function GetSecretAsync() As Task(Of String)
        Const KEY_VAULT_NAME As String = "samplevault326"
        Const KEY_NAME As String = "secret1"
        Dim kvUri = $"https://{KEY_VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net"

        Dim credential = New DefaultAzureCredential()
        Dim client = New SecretClient(New Uri(kvUri), credential)
        Dim secret = Await client.GetSecretAsync(KEY_NAME)

        If secret Is Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("Secret not found")
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Return secret.Value.Value
        End If
    End Function
End Module

Ensure you are passing the correct parameters, such as key vault name, secret name, and authenticating with the correct credentials.
Output:
Secret value: Welcome!!!


Reference:
Quickstart - Azure Key Vault secrets client library for .NET | Microsoft Learn
